# Showing object's name instead of Id in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model, controller

Consider I have a Model like this:

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And example data:

Id ----- Name ----- ParentId

01 ----- Parent ----- 00

02 ----- Child ------- 01

In the Index.html view I'm showing a list of Items in this table:

[image]

So what if I want to show Parent's Name instead of ParentId? I can separate Parent's model from the child's model, but I want them to be in the same table.

Comment: I think you need to relate the two class tables.

Comment: @Llazar it's just one class.

Comment: Then Parent's Name what is?

Comment: Add a Parent property of `Branch` type and use it's `Name` property.

Comment: What does your view look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple approaches I've decided to use a join, something like this:

As my model:

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

As my controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var branches = db.Branches;
        var query = from child in branches
            join parent in branches on child.ParentId equals parent.Id into parentJoin
            select new 
            {
                Id = child.Id,
                ParentId = child.ParentId,
                Name = child.Name,
                ParentName = parentJoin.FirstOrDefault().Name
            };
        var result = query.ToList().Select(e => new Branch
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            ParentId = e.ParentId,
            Name = e.Name,
            ParentName = e.ParentName
        }).ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
```

and as my View:

```
@model List<Rouyesh_Database.Models.Branch>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
if (item.ParentId == null)
{
    <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a ViewModel to handle this situation.

```
public class BranchVM : Branch
{
    // because it extends Branch it has Id, Name, and ParentId
    public string ParentName {get;set;}
}
```

Get the fields in your business logic then pass this viewmodel to a view that accepts a BranchVM as its Model and voila.